# Where do I add dotnet user-secrets

Tags: asp.net-identity, configure

I'm following along on a MS tutorial on adding user roles and I do not understand in their instructions where I am supposed to add the bit of code regarding the dotnet user-secrets, when configuring a test identity. Here is a screenshot form the tutorial:

[Configure Test Account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvcPy.png)

Does this mean this bit of code should go in the .csproj file and if so, where?

Thanks for any and all assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a more general yet complete tutorial about `user-secrets` as follows:

- `mkdir Temporary`: create a directory `Temporary`
- `cd Temporary`: set active directory to `Temporary`
- `dotnet new webapi -o Api`: create a webapi project named `Api`.
- `dotnet user-secrets --project Api init`:  Generate `UserSecretsId`  in `Api.csproj`. Note that `secrets.json` has not been created yet.
- `dotnet user-secrets --project Api set YourPassword p@$$word`: `secrets.json` will be created at `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\<Replace This With UserSecretsId>`.

Notes:

- If you invoke `dotnet user-secrets ...` from `Api` folder, then `--project Api` is not needed anymore.
- `secrets.json` can be shared with multiple projects if `UserSecretsId` is shared among the projects. Copy `<UserSecretsId>f58edfcd-2e0b-4842-9272-6a9cb22e5ff1</UserSecretsId>` from `Api.csproj` and paste it to `OtherProject.csproj`.